# SAS: Set current folder to the folder containing the running program

Tags: sas

I've just started learning SAS because I'm required to use it for a statistics course.  For this course, the university provides SAS 9.2 through their virtual-machine setup:  I make a reservation in their system, they generate a VM on one of their servers, and I connect to the VM using Microsoft's Remote Desktop client.  The virtual machines are generated and erased per session; settings are reset every time, and files must be stored on my client computer (which is accessible in the VM by a UNC path).

Within this setup, when I open a program file stored on my laptop, I've only been able to access the accompanying data files (each stored in the same folder as the program) either by hardcoding the full path or by updating the "current folder" setting at the beginning of each session.  The first is problematic because it means the program won't run anywhere else - in particular, when I email it to the professor.  The second is inconvenient, because browsing to this particular UNC path is time consuming, and I already have to browse to the same path to open the program file.

I want to make this easier by programmatically setting the current folder to the folder containing the program.  Then I could just open the file and get to work.  I've found some examples of [getting the filename of the program file](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Get_Name_of_Program), of [getting the path to a fileref](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Tips:Using_PATHNAME_to_Retrieve_a_Physical_Path), and of (link limit exceeded) setting the current folder, but I haven't been able to combine them in the right way.  Please connect the dots for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Complete Answer:

SAS's obtuse notation requires some strange delimiter fiddling to combine my partial solution (finding the path) with @Bob Duell's partial solution (setting the current folder).  There seem to be two key rules involved:

- &var is expanded in double-quoted strings ("&var"), but not single-quoted strings ('&var')
- Quotes in &var are not treated as delimiters after expansion

So the solution is to compute a string of the quoted path (where the quotes are part of the string), and expand that within a double-quoted parameter to X or SYSTEM:

```
%let qsrc=%str(%")&src%str(%");
X "cd &qsrc"
```

It's not required to store the string, both &src and &qsrc can be expanded in-place, which yields a single statement solution:

```
X "cd %str(%")%substr(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH),1,%eval(%length(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH))-%length(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME))))%str(%")";
```

This executes correctly, but breaks the syntax coloring in the GUI.  Within a string, `%str(%")` and `""` both expand to `"`, so replacing `%str(%")` with `""` both executes correctly and is colored correctly in the GUI:

```
X "cd ""%substr(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH),1,%eval(%length(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH))-%length(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME))))""";
```

This inherits the limitation that it only works when SAS_EXECFILEPATH and SAS_EXECFILENAME are defined, which is the case when running from within the Windows GUI editor.  It's also subject to any limitations on in the "cd" command, which [SAS intercepts](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#sassession.htm) rather than invoking the Windows command line.  I expect it will fail on paths containing quotes.

Comment: Why not just use double-double quotes? `x "cd ""&SRC""" ;`

Comment: Because I didn't know that was an option until I read your comment.  What criteria should be used to choose between `""` and `%str(%")`?  Is there any case where they're not equivalent?

Comment: Apparently `"%str(%")"` confuses the GUI parser, completely breaking the syntax highlighting, even though it executes correctly.  `""` both executes and syntax-highlights correctly.

Comment: You're trying to pass double-quotes to the command line (in this case, because your filepath has spaces in it). But you need the macro variable to resolve too, hence the need for double-double quotes. SAS document the double-double quote in the SYSTASK documentation, http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-stmt-systask.htm

Comment: `""` seems to work in any string, not just for SYSTASK.  I wasn't able to find any overview of SAS's string handling (closest I've found is [macro quoting](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#tw3514-overvwqt.htm)), but there seem to be at least 3 ways to get double-quotes into a string: `""`, [`"%str(%")`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514str.htm), and [`QUOTE(s)`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245937.htm).

Answer (score 3):

To programmatically change the Windows current directory from SAS, you can use the `X` command, which is what really happens when you use the "Change current folder" dialog box:

```
x 'cd "\\computername\share name\folder"';
```

You can also do this using the `SYSTEM` data step function, a method I prefer because you get a return code (but more typing of course):

```
data _null_;
   rc = system( 'cd "\\computername\share name\folder"' );
   if rc = 0 
      then putlog 'Command successful';
      else putlog 'Command failed';
run;
```

Note the UNC path is surrounded with double-quotes, which is necessary if the path contains blanks.

Of course, this still requires you to manually type in the command, but it might be something you could add to the program source code.  If your VM environment allowed you to maintain some permanent presence on the server, you could save this command into a start-up file.

I would ask your professor for advice; if you are working with data given to you as part of your class, you may only need to send just the source code.  On the other hand, if you are creating output data as part of your assignment, your professor might want your to deliver source code and SAS data sets.  Surely he or she will have some procedure.

Comment: I want it to change to the folder containing the code, not a hardcoded path.  Pasting your code and hardcoding my UNC path fails.  The [X command](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-cmd-x.htm) and the [SYSTEM Function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245956.htm) both seem to be using the Windows command line to change the current directory, but the Windows command line refuses to use a UNC path as a current directory.  Can you confirm that this works for a UNC path?

Comment: Yes, it works with a UNC path. If you submit the X command by itself (`x;`), your SAS session will suspend and a Windows command box should open where you can type commands. Use that to discover the correct `cd` command to change directory. Type `exit` to close the box and return to your SAS session.

Comment: Looks like it failed because a newline got inserted in the middle of the pasted path... now it works for a hardcoded path, but not for a computed path.  My partial answer gets the right path, but using `rc = system( 'cd "&src"' );` fails.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Also, the windows command box says "CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories", so I guess SAS isn't just running every command through that.

Comment: Your attempt to use the `system` function does not work because you have a macro variable inside the single quotes, which will not resolve. Can't say anything about your other error.

Comment: @Polyergic Correct - the Windows `cd` command does not support UNC paths.  The simplest workaround I've found for this is to use the `net use r: \\xxx\xxx` to map the UNC path to the unmapped R: and then use `cd` to change to R:.  You can resolve a UNC path to see if there is an equivalent local or mapped drive that already exists but it's not pretty code and it's not in SAS.  If you choose to do that then a simple google search should yield what you're looking for.

Comment: @RobPenridge I am clearly wrong. I would swear that I tested this in my environment before responding but obviously not.  Please change your comment to an answer so I can delete my answer.

Comment: cmd.exe refuses to use a UNC path as a current directory, but SAS can use a UNC path as it's current folder.  The surprising thing is that the SAS X command allows a cd to a UNC path.  It seems that SAS is not just spawning cmd.exe to execute commands; [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#sassession.htm) says "SAS intercepts the change directory command and then changes drive commands and changes its current folder."  (I would prefer an API with separate calls rather than intercepted commands.)

Comment: @BobDuell Looks like you were right after all Bob ;-)  Don't delete your answer!

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:  One way to get the containing folder from the filename of the program file

Spread out & logging steps:

```
/* Find PathName of folder containing program */
%let FullName=%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH);
%put FullName: &FullName.;
%let FullLen=%length(&FullName);
%put FullLen: &FullLen.;
%let BaseName=%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME);
%put BaseName: &BaseName.;
%let BaseLen=%length(&BaseName);
%put BaseLen: &BaseLen.;
%let PathLen=%eval(&FullLen.-&BaseLen.);
%put PathLen: &PathLen.;
%let PathName=%substr(&FullName,1,&PathLen);
%put PathName: &PathName.;
```

Consolidated & silent:

```
/* Find src folder */
%let src=%substr(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH),1,%eval(%length(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH))-%length(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME))));
```

This only works when SAS_EXECFILEPATH and SAS_EXECFILENAME are defined, and it's not clear when that is.  It does work when using the Windows GUI editor.